# Analyzing logical form of the statements

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I have four statements given as exercises in the book: *How to prove it*.

Sa : Alice and Bob are not both in the room.

Sb :  Alice and Bob are both not in the room.

Sc :  Either Alice or Bob is not in the room.

Sd : Neither Alice nor Bob is in the room.

Let A : Alice in the room and B: Bob is in the room.

Sa :  $A \oplus B$. I think Either Alice or Bob in the room,but not both Alice and Bob.

Sb : $\neg{(A \lor B)}$. Sb will be false if any of Alice or Bob or both in the room.

Sc: $\neg{A} \lor \neg{B}$.

Sd: $\neg{(A \lor B)}$.

Can you verify my analysis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming the exercise here asked you to translate the sentences into propositional calculus. Sa should be translated as $\neg (A \wedge B)$; it would have been $A \oplus B$ if it had said "Either Alice or Bob are in the room, but not both". For Sb, the more literal translation would be $\neg A \wedge \neg B$, but in classical logic what you wrote is equivalent, by one of DeMorgan's laws. Your translations of Sc and Sd are exactly right.

Answer (score 1):

I also think Sa should be
$$\neg (A \land B), $$

or

[image].

which includes the event your translation missed that neither Alice nor Bob is in the room.